# How to initialize datetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, syntax

I've been trying to use the datetime library in python to create a datetime object with this value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. However, I keep getting an error that the year is out of range. How can I properly initialize this?

Comment: If by chance you were aiming to initialize it to date '0' so you could check your variable for a value in like a loop before it may exist (and not wanting to set it to an int or string or such and then have the 'expense' of retyping)... another option is just to set it to None.  You probably weren't, but I was :-)

Comment: Gregorian calendar starts at year 1. If you think that doesn't make any sense then try asking a person to start counting numbers. Odds are they'll go: ONE, two, three, four... It's all in the eye of the beholder. Also, would you really want to be able to initialize the month and day fields to '00'? Is there a month in a year prior to January commonly labeled month ONE?  :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no year 0, because people couldn't figure out how to count properly back then.

The closest you can get:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.min
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

In [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), the constant for MINYEAR is 1:

> datetime.MINYEAR
>
> The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MINYEAR
> is 1.

To initialize the earliest possible date you would do:

```
import datetime

earliest_date = datetime.datetime.min 
# OR
earliest_date = datetime.datetime(1,1,1,0,0)

print earliest_date.isoformat()
```

Which outputs:

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a `datetime.timedelta` object, you can use the following statement:

```
lapseTime = datetime.now() - datetime.now()
```

`lapseTime` will be initialized to `datetime.timedelta(0)`. You can then use `lapseTime` to do arithmetic calculations with other `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

"How to initialize datetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in Python?"

No allowed, see manual datetime.

Alternative solution to the question is the minimum datetime:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.min, datetime.time.min)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

found while reading:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I needed a minimum datetime object which is POSIX compliant, so I found I could get that from

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
```

which gives 1st Jan 1970 00:00:00:0000. But you need to be really careful with this, the datetime object returned is naive (no tz info).

Add utc timezone when using this:

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
[>] datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Oddly, if you have to convert back to POSIX with timestamp() from a **naive** datetime, it throws an error for anything less than 2nd Jan 1970 1am

```
datetime(1970,1,2,1,0,0).timestamp()
[>] 86400.0
```

You can fix this by adding timezone:

```
datetime(1970,1,1).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
[>] 0.0
```

Also, in version 3.2, `strftime()` method was restricted to years >= 1000. ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes:%7E:text=In%20version%203.2%2C%20strftime()%20method%20was%20restricted%20to%20years%20%3E%3D%201000.))